# Table Scrolling application crash

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, uitableview

On scrolling tableview, my application crashes and show optional value is not nil . First time, my condition is executed and work fine for me but when we scroll and event condition is execute and application crashes. Please have look at it. I am newer in ios. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  let identifier = "CustumCell"
            var cell: CustumCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? CustumCell
            if cell == nil {
                var nib:Array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustumCell", owner: self, options: nil)
                if (myArray[indexPath.row]["type"] as? String == "event"){
                       cell = nib[5] as? CustumCell
                } else if (myArray[indexPath.row]["type"] as? String == "status"){
                    cell = nib[0] as? CustumCell

                }else if (myArray[indexPath.row]["type"] as? String == "tag"){
                    cell = nib[7] as? CustumCell
                }
                else {
                  cell = nib[8] as? CustumCell
                }




        if (myArray[indexPath.row]["type"] as? String == "event"){
                    print(myArray[indexPath.row]["profile_image"])
                    cell.homeEvent.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:myArray[indexPath.row]["profile_image"] as? String ?? ""))
                    cell.homeeventtitleName.text = myArray[indexPath.row]["related_name"] as? String ?? ""
                     cell.homeeventUsername.text = myArray[indexPath.row]["related_user_name"]! as? String ?? ""
                     cell.homeeventStatus.text = myArray[indexPath.row]["status"]! as? String ?? ""
                    let event = myArray[indexPath.row]["event"]! as? [[String:AnyObject]]
                    if (event?.count == 0){

                    } else {
                    let startDate = event![0]["start_date"] as? String ?? ""
                    let endDate = event![0]["start_month"] as? String ?? ""
                    cell.homeeventDate.text =  startDate + endDate
                     cell.homeeventfirst.text = event![0]["event_name"] as? String ?? ""
                    cell.homeeventsecond.text = event![0]["location"] as? String ?? ""
                    cell.homeeventthird.text = event![0]["start_time"] as? String ?? ""
                    }
                    cell.homeeventlastSeen.text = myArray[indexPath.row]["activity_date"] as? String ?? ""

                     cell.homeeventImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:  event![0]["image"] as? String ?? ""))
                     cell.likeLabel.text = myArray[indexPath.row]["like"] as? String ?? ""
                    cell.commentLabel.text = myArray[indexPath.row]["comment"] as? String ?? ""
                }
```

Comment: What is the error? post your error too.

Comment: not nil optional value

Comment: In such cases, the mostly issue is because of  an index is getting out of bound, put condition so that table is not trying to fetch more number object from an array which is not there.

Comment: please post full error. your code looks okay to me.

Comment: try to add a `Exception Breakpoint`. It will stop on the line where its crashing  .